# ORACLE DMU (database migration assistant for unicode) Tool

Tags: oracle, migration, tablespaces, character-set, unicode

Reading the documentation for Oracle DMU tool, when I try the step create a step for DMU Repository tablespace the document says to use the result of the query for initial size. However; I could not run the query even as the `sys` account. Below is the query from [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51608_01/doc.20/e48475/ch4scenarios.htm#DUMAG247)

```
    SELECT CEIL((t.cnt*300+c.cnt*1000)/1048576)||' MB'
               "Initial Size"
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM sys.tab$) t,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
               FROM sys.col$
              WHERE obj# IN (SELECT obj# FROM sys.tab$)
                 AND BITAND(property,65536)=0
                 AND type# IN (1,8,58,96,112)
                 AND charsetform=1) c
```

Comment: perhaps include the error message you received and any debugging steps you tried to resolve it. See also [ask]

Comment: Thanks for giving me an advice, I was careless before asking. The only message I got was charsetform is incorrect. I was looking on the internet and there was no clues. In addition. I did not understand why Oracle document comes up with that query. Sorry, I am new in this area

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the query,it just gives you minimum table space size .On 11gR2 I get the size as 16MB and on 19c cdb/pdb  8MB. Just create a tablespace with large size with autoextend on.

`CREATE TABLESPACE DMUREPO DATAFILE '/u03/oradata/ORCL/DMUREP01.DBF' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M  -- change datafile location based on your environment`